# Error in processOrder Cloud Function in Razorpay firebase Webapp

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, razorpay

I'm encountering an issue with my `processOrder` Cloud Function in Firebase, and I'm hoping to get some assistance in resolving it. Here's the problem:

**Description:** I have a Cloud Function called `processOrder` that handles payment processing for my e-commerce application. The function uses the Razorpay API for payments. However, when I trigger the function, I consistently receive the error.

**Context:**

- I'm building an e-commerce application using Firebase.
- The `processOrder` function is responsible for handling payments via the Razorpay API.
- I have configured the Firebase environment variables to include the Razorpay API key, which is loaded correctly.

**Code:**

Here's the relevant part of my `processOrder` Cloud Function code

```
exports.processOrder = functions
    .region("asia-south1")
    .https.onRequest((request, response) => {
      return cors(request, response, async () => {
        try {
          const {
            amount,
            orderId,
            name: custName,
            mobile: custMobile,
            email: custEmail = "", // Default to an empty string if not provided
            userUID,
          } = request.body;

          // Access the Razorpay API key from Firebase configuration
          

          const options = {
            key: "",
            amount: amount,
            currency: "INR",
            name: "EasyPizy", // your business name
            order_id: orderId,
            callback_url:
              "url",
            prefill: {
              name: custName, // your customer's name
              email: custEmail,
              contact: custMobile,
            },
            theme: {
              color: "#ff6347",
            },
            modal: {
              confirm_close: true,
            },
            customer_id: userUID,
            remember_customer: true,
            hidden: {
              contact: true,
              email: true,
            },
            send_sms_hash: true,
          };

          const rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
          rzp1.open();

          rzp1.on("payment.success", (response) => {
            // Payment success logic here
            console.log("Payment successful:", response);

            // Store the payment details in Firestore
            const paymentDetails = {
              razorpay_payment_id: response.razorpay_payment_id,
              razorpay_order_id: response.razorpay_order_id,
              razorpay_signature: response.razorpay_signature,
            };

            // Define the path to the Firestore document
            const orderDocumentPath = `users/${userUID}/orders/${orderId}`;

            // Get a Firestore reference to the document
            const orderDocRef = admin.firestore().doc(orderDocumentPath);

            // Set the payment details in Firestore
            orderDocRef
                .set(paymentDetails, {merge: true})
                .then(() => {
                  console.log("Payment details stored in Firestore.");
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  console.error(
                      "Error storing payment details in Firestore:",
                      error,
                  );
                });

            // Send a success response to the client
            response.status(200).send("Payment successful");
          });

          rzp1.on("payment.error", async (error) => {
            // Payment error logic here
            console.error("Payment error:", error);

            // Send an error response to the client
            response.status(500).send("Payment error");

            // Update the status field in Firestore to "failed"
            const orderDocumentPath = `users/${userUID}/orders/${orderId}`;
            const orderDocRef = admin.firestore().doc(orderDocumentPath);

            try {
              await orderDocRef.set({status: "failed"}, {merge: true});
              console.log("Order status updated to 'failed' in Firestore.");
            } catch (updateError) {
              console.error(
                  "Error updating order status in Firestore:",
                  updateError,
              );
            }
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error processing the order:", error);
          // Send an error response to the client in case of any exception
          response.status(500).send("Error processing the order");
        }
      });
    });


clientside browser code:
// Event listener for the "Proceed to Pay" buttons
const proceedToPayButtons = document.querySelectorAll("#proceedToPayBtn");
proceedToPayButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    
        const requestData = {
          amount: tempCartData.finalAmount * 100,
        };

        // Define the fetch options with CORS headers for createOrder
        const fetchOptions = {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            // Add CORS headers here
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(requestData),
        };

        // Make an HTTP POST request to the Firebase Cloud Function for createOrder
        try {
          const response = await fetch(
            "url",
            fetchOptions
          );

          if (response.ok) {
            // The request to createOrder was successful, you can handle the response here
            const data = await response.json();

            const orderDocumentId = data.id; // Assuming data.id contains the desired document ID

            // Define the full path to the document using doc()
            const orderDocRef = doc(db, `users/${userUID}/orders/${orderDocumentId}`);

            try {
              // Set the data for the document
              await setDoc(orderDocRef, {
                orderId: data.id,
                amount: data.amount,
                amount_paid: data.amount_paid,
                amount_due: data.amount_due,
                receipt: data.receipt,
                status: data.status,
                created_at: new Date(data.created_at * 1000),
              });
              console.log("Firestore document created successfully.");

              // After creating the order, initiate the payment processing by calling processOrder
              const reqData = {
                amount: tempCartData.finalAmount * 100,
                orderID: orderDocumentId,
                custName: tempCartData.fullName,
                custMobile: tempCartData.phoneNumber,
                custEmail: tempCartData.email || "",
                userUID: userUID,
              };

              // Define the fetch options with CORS headers for processOrder
              const fetchOptionsForProcessOrder = {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "application/json",
                  // Add CORS headers here
                  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(reqData),
              };

              // Make a POST request to the Cloud Function for processOrder
              try {
                const processOrderResponse = await fetch(
                  "url",
                  fetchOptionsForProcessOrder
                );

                if (processOrderResponse.ok) {
                  // Handle the response from the Cloud Function for processOrder
                  // Only check the status code, don't parse JSON response data
                  console.log("Request to Cloud Function (processOrder) was successful. Status code:", processOrderResponse.status);

                  // You can implement further logic here based on the response
                } else {
                  // Handle the case where the request to processOrder was not successful
                  console.error("Error in Cloud Function request (processOrder):", processOrderResponse.statusText);
                }
              } catch (error) {
                // Handle the case where the request to processOrder encountered an error
                console.error("Error in Cloud Function request (processOrder):", error);
              }
            } catch (error) {
              // Update the status in Firestore to "failed" on error
              await setDoc(orderDocRef, {
                status: "failed",
              });
              console.error("Error:", error);
            }
          } else {
            // Handle the case where the request to createOrder was not successful
            console.error("Error in createOrder request:", response.statusText);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          // Handle the case where the request to createOrder encountered an error
          console.error("Error in createOrder request:", error);
        }
        console.log("Temporary cart data updated successfully.");
      } else {
        console.error("Temporary cart data not found.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error updating temporary cart data:", error);
    }
  });
});
```

**Expected Behavior:**

I expect the `processOrder` function to open the Razorpay modal, process payments, and store payment details in Firestore upon successful payment.

**Actual Behavior:**

Instead, I'm encountering the 'key_id' error as mentioned above, and the payment process doesn't proceed as expected.

**Steps Taken:**

- I have double-checked my Firebase configuration to ensure that the Razorpay API key is correctly set.
- I reviewed the code for any typos or errors but couldn't find any.
- I attempted to trigger the function multiple times, but the error persists.

**Request for Assistance:**

I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this issue with the 'key_id' error. Are there any common pitfalls or best practices I should be aware of when using the Razorpay API with Firebase?

Comment: Your question twice mentions there is some "key_id" error, but you never show or explain what that is. You should copy the exact error message into the question and indicate clearly which line of code causes it.

Comment: Even though I have hardcoded API keys in the code, the error message continues to indicate that 'key_id' is mandatory. I haven't used the 'key_id' variable anywhere in the code, which points to a potential issue with how the API keys are being accessed or utilized.  i have included it at the top of the code const instance = new Razorpay({
  key_id: "",
  key_secret: "",
});     instance first works with createorder function to create orderID (it is working good), ten processOrder function is given above

Comment: const cloudFunctionResponse = await fetch(
                  "link",
                  fetchOptionsForProcessOrder
                );              tis line in browserside code seems to cause error